# Use a Variable instead of the term MYSQLI_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysqli

To keep the Array type dynamic in the `mysqli_fetch_array` query, I would like to use a variable instead of the term `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. When I try the below code:

```
$array_type = "MYSQLI_ASSOC";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,$array_type)){
echo $row["name"];
}
```

I get the below error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /var/www/dca/query_results.php on line 28

I would want to avoid using `if` and `else` statements if case possible.

Comment: `MYSQLI_ASSOC` is a constant.

Comment: Vote to close as typo

Comment: see my answer it may help you.

Comment: It's the first time I see the accepted answer with downvotes !

Comment: @ths A bad answer and an inexperienced Questioner :)

Answer (score 3):

`MYSQLI_ASSOC` is a number, not a string. try with

```
$array_type = MYSQLI_ASSOC;
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact, `MYSQLI_ASSOC` is a predefined `PHP` `constant`(which holds an `integer` that helps the `mysqli_result` class to know the type of the fetching that should be used). So, you need to assign its value to the `$array_type` variable notnlike its name as a `string`:

```
$array_type = MYSQLI_ASSOC; // no quotes nor apostrophes.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, $array_type)) {
  echo $row["name"];
}
```

To make things more dynamic as I understood you want, you can create an array that holds the different fetching styles and then just call that array and by indicating the desired fetching style using the appropriate index:

```
$array_type = [MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, MYSQLI_BOTH]; // array containing the fetching styles.
/**
* $array_type[0] => associative array.
* $array_type[1] => default array(the indexes are numbers).
* $array_type[2] => the both styles are used.
**/
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, $array_type[0])) {
  echo $row["name"];
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score -1):

Second parameter is optional integer constant and it requires an integer value not string, [see details here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

so you have to use any of the following

```
$array_type = MYSQLI_ASSOC; // 1
$array_type = MYSQLI_NUM; // 2
$array_type = MYSQLI_BOTH; // 3
```

or

```
$array_type = 1; //MYSQLI_ASSOC;
$array_type = 2; //MYSQLI_NUM;
$array_type = 3; //MYSQLI_BOTH;
```

above 3 constants are defined as below in MySQLi

```
define ('MYSQLI_ASSOC', 1);
define ('MYSQLI_NUM', 2);
define ('MYSQLI_BOTH', 3);
```

Comment: Not the second option, incase the developers decide to change the values associated with the predefined constant

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i have not suggested 3rd options i have just described that that is how it is already defined by PHP :) please read the text above.

Comment: Ah right I see now.